# Remote query (openquery) to linked server fails after upgrading to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server

Problem started after upgrading to SQL Server 2016 Enterprise edition.
Linked and local servers both were upgraded to ver.13.0.4435.0

I've tried the following:
 Drop/create the linked server after the upgrade to 2016. The problem persists.

This is the code snippet where error occurs:

```
SELECT t.NAME
    , t.Disabled
FROM openquery([Linked_Server], 'select t.Name, t.Disabled 
    from [Linked_Server].[Database-1A].[dbo].[My_tbl] t where t.ID=232627') t;
```

And the error message:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Linked_Server" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
>   Msg 5000 Could not find server 'linked server' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: (FWIW, it's unlikely this exact query worked before the upgrade, again, unless there was a loopback linked server that was changed or removed as a separate part of the upgrade.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you're sending *to* the linked server (via `OPENQUERY`) shouldn't also contain its own reference to the linked server (via 4-part name), unless the linked server has its own loopback linked server with the same linked server name (and even if it does, I wouldn't try to stack linked servers like that). Try:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Disabled
FROM OPENQUERY
(
   [Linked_Server], 
   N'select t.Name, t.Disabled 
     from [Database-1A].[dbo].[My_tbl] AS t 
     where t.ID=232627;'
) AS t;
```